# Jquery: How to remove extra blank spaces that are present at the end of the string

Tags: jquery

I have a string

```
"Check Box  "
```

The string contain the extra spaces at the end. I want to remove those extra spaces as i am going to explode the middle spaces using '_'.

The problem is when i use explode function it also converts the end spaces to '_'

How to deal with that????

Comment: [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And with jquery:
`$.trim("Check Box  ");`

Answer (score 1):

Use `trim` before replace .

```
var str="Check Box  "
str = $.trim(str);
//Your replce logic goes
```

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery required for this:

```
"Check Box  ".trim()
```

Comment: Though be careful if you need to support IE versions < 9.  See:  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp